Are my S3 ceph bucket synchronized or synchronizing?
I have two pacific ceph cluster.
ceph --version
ceph version 16.2.10-160.el8cp (6977980612de1db28e41e0a90ff779627cde7a8c) pacific (stable)

(that is 5.3.2)
There is a dual replication set between the two sites (named gondor and rohan below).
I am new to ceph and replications, I started a synchronisation 3 days ago, using this command from rohan side:
radosgw-admin data sync init --bucket=bm.test.sync.bucket1 --source-zone=gondor

now on both side, every time I issue radosgw-admin sync status I get thoses two results:
from gondor
          realm UUID (middleearth)
      zonegroup UUID (thirdage)
           zone UUID (gondor)
   current time 2024-12-19T07:15:45Z
zonegroup features enabled:
                   disabled: resharding
  metadata sync no sync (zone is master)
      data sync source: UUID (rohan)
                        syncing
                        full sync: 0/128 shards
                        incremental sync: 128/128 shards
                        data is behind on 3 shards
                        behind shards: [13,17,52]
                        oldest incremental change not applied: 2024-12-19T08:15:32.613647+0100 [13]

from rohan
          realm UUID (middleearth)
      zonegroup UUID (thirdage)
           zone UUID (rohan)
   current time 2024-12-19T07:34:55Z
zonegroup features enabled:
                   disabled: resharding
  metadata sync syncing
                full sync: 0/64 shards
                incremental sync: 64/64 shards
                metadata is caught up with master
      data sync source: UUID (gondor)
                        syncing
                        full sync: 0/128 shards
                        incremental sync: 128/128 shards
                        123 shards are recovering
                        recovering shards: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127]

Questions :

are my cluster synching ? (that is, will I get less "recovering shards" at some point ?)

I can understand there is a replication latency and a little discrepencies on most recents objects.
However, my buckets don't seems to have same contents on both side.
In one particular bucket

on gondor side : two objects : one from june 2022, one empty from january 2024
on rohan side only one empty from january 2024

I tought above command would resynchronize bucket.
(radosgw-admin data sync init --bucket=bm.test.sync.bucket1 --source-zone=gondor)
Can sync be achieved ? If yes, how ?
edit 1:

typos in data sync, was data sync init, not data sync status


How should a „status“ command issue a sync? It’s just a status. Try ‚radosgw-admin data sync init‘ and ‚… data sync run‘ instead. I’m nowhere near a cluster right now, so the commands might be slightly different.

yes, you are right, was probably an init rather than a status, I'll recheck session log.

Did you also run radosgw-admin data sync run? You should see traffic on the Ceph pool(s) and Client IO if it works. If it doesn't, check the rgw logs for any hints.
